# link php forms to divID in html page

Tags: php, css, html

I have a bunch of PHP forms which is working perfect. I am working on Integrating all the forms into a single HTML page so that on the click it opens the form in the same HTML page. I am new to HTML5 and took some HTML file and modified it.

I am facing two issues.
1. On click of the options in top of the form(from drop-down) it opens the page in the new tab. I need to open it in the center of the HTML page.
2. I need to create in-line drop-down boxes, the second drop-down menu is not showing up correctly.

It may be trivial or I  am doing something completely wrong?
Experts, please tell me what I am missing..

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>DG SIM</title>

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7; IE=EmulateIE9">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/ASSIM/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="/ASSIM/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/ASSIM/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



    <style type="text/css">
        .x-panel-framed {
            padding: 0;
        }
       #div_g2 {
                background-color: #FFFFFF;
                        margin: 10 10 10 10;
       }
button#inner {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #3498DB;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 110%;
  width: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.dropdown-menu form :focus{
color:black;
background-color: none;
}

.buttonWidth {
width: 160px
}


    </style>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    pageLoaded();

});


function pageLoaded() {
//need to call a php script here too so that it shows up on the cneter page.
}


Code:

    </script>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:#0067AC;">
    <div align="center"><img src="img/aff_new.gif" /><img src="img/corp_id_small.gif" /></div>

    <!-- Device options-->
     <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle buttonWidth" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Device Options
      <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="/ASSIM/addDevice.php" target="div_g2">Onboarding Devices</a></li>
            <li><a target="div_g2" href="/ASSIM/trialdeviceActions.php">Device Actions</a</li>
            </ul>
      </div>

    <!-- DATA Option

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle buttonWidth" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">SCEF Options
      <span class="caret"></span></button>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a target="div_g2" href="/ASSIM/addSF.php">ADD SCEF</a>
              <li><a target="div_g2" href="/ASSIM/trial.html">Delete SCEF</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    -->
          <div style="background-color:#0067AC; position: absolute; left: 10px; right: 10px; top: 95px; bottom: 10px;" > <div>
          <div id='div_g2' style='height:500px; top: 30px;'></div>
       </div>


    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: You want something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/phutis/rw3qv829/

Comment: Thanks. The form needs to fit into the middle pane.(white layout) now it pops up in the same page but not exactly inside the div. should I go with Iframes? Basically I need a header and content pane and the header will have drop down box and on click it calls a php script and loads the form in the content pane.